# SymbolSource get source code

Tags: .net, nuget, symbols

Is there any way to get package source code from SymbolSource. I want to just download source code zip (like at GitHub) or at least browse the source code but I don't see how I can do it.

I have integrated SymbolSource+NuGet+VisualStudio and I can see some class source code by clicking "Go To Definition" but now I want to serf the whole project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the way a symbol server works, but there exists a solution to get what you want explained in [this article](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2010/06/06/getting-pdbs-and-source-when-you-can-t-access-your-symbol-server.aspx).

It boils down to:

You'll need to first run SYMCHK.EXE (part of [debugging tools for windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx)) on all the directories you want symbols for.

Then use SRCTOOL.EXE with the –x switch and the PDB file you want, SRCTOOL.EXE will execute all the version control commands embedded in the PDB file and get the source for you.